# Can a Python function have multiple return types?

Tags: python, types, signature, return-type

Is it possible for a Python function to return different types depending on the if-else case?

```
def return_different() -> [String, List]:

     a = random.randint(1, 10)
     if a%2 == 0:
         return []
     else:
         return "odd"
```

So in one case, it could return a String, or in another, it could return a List. Is this possible in Python with function signatures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you want a `Union` type:

```
def return_different() -> Union[str, List]:

# Or in Python 3.10+

def return_different() -> str | list:
```

I would reconsider this function though. Returning different types without proper thought makes your caller's life more difficult since strings and lists don't have a lot of capability overlap (`Sequence` basically), so you'll force them to do a runtime typecheck to decide how to use the data; depending on how they want to use the returned data.

Comment: To be exact, from python3.10

Comment: @sudden_appearance Ignore my last comment. You're right. I could have sworn I was using `|` before 3.10.

Comment: Thank you! The Union is exactly what I was wondering about

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you not must to declare on the return type and then you can return what you want.

Answer (score -2):

In Python, there are no types, so you can return whatever you want. That means you can return more than one type of thing; e.g in your example above sometimes a list is returned, other times a string is returned. The function signature is merely an annotation in your code; it does not enforce type safety. Also, technically your return signature above means that we should expect to see a return value of a list containing a string and a list. It does not mean a list OR a string is returned.